# How to override variable library in Azure DevOps Server Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We need to be able to deploy to two different deployment groups, Development1 and QA for example, but use the Development variables in the QA release.  We actually have 10 different releases that double up like this.

I've set up 2 stage/environment in a release definition.  Development1 runs first and then QA is deployed by using an after stage trigger.  The QA deployment needs to use the variables from Development1, not the default variables in the QA library based on the environment name.  I need some way to have teh QA deployment use the Development1 variable set.

It looks like yaml has a way to do this but, we aren't using yaml for release definitions.  I'm not coming up with a solution and hope someone may have an idea how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Devops Release pipeline , the `Development1 stage` and `QA stage` are independent.

So there is no direct method could share variable from stage1 to stage2 (release pipeline).

**Workaround**

You need to store Development1 stage output variables in one storage(e.g. keyvault, azure function or rest api). Then the `QA stage` could get the variable in the storage.

For example:  store it in Azure Key vault with the task [Azure Key Vault actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-azurekeyvault&targetId=3ec66d6c-317d-423e-a056-b014031f2871) or [Write Secrets to Key Vault](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cboroson.cboroson-WriteSecrets&targetId=3ec66d6c-317d-423e-a056-b014031f2871).

Another way is use [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to add it as the release variable with powershell script:

```
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.0
```

In next stage, it can access and get variable from Release Variables.

By the way, Yaml now supports passing variables directly from stage1 to stage2 via [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages). But it is currently limited to yaml based.

Comment: That might work if I was talking about a few variables but I'm passing/using 2 or 3 Variable groups from the library.  I'd have to write 50,60 maybe a 100 variables more.  I need to be able to pass a variable group or to tell the QA deployment to use the Development1 Variable group(s).  A single release definition for QA needs to be told to use the variable groups assigned to as many as 20 other Stage variable groups in stead of the ones that are setup for QA.  One time QA is run it should use the Development1 variable groups.  The next time QA needs to use the variables that are for Test1.

Comment: Yes. If you use the variable group, it could work too. Here is a suggestion ticket with the same requirements: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/598551/add-ability-to-persist-variables-across-release-st-1.html You could vote and add comment in it.